# Why doesnt this xPath (c#) work?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Got this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<video xmlns="UploadXSD">
  <title>
    A vid with Pete
  </title>
  <description>
  Petes vid
  </description>
  <contributor>
    Pete
  </contributor>
  <subject>
    Cat 2
  </subject>
</video>
```

And this xpath:

```
videoToAdd.Title = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/video/title").InnerXml;
```

And im getting an 'object reference not set to an instance of an object'.  Any ideas why this is a valid xpath from what I can see and it used to work...

Comment: Can you show the doc initializing statement?

Comment: `videoToAdd` or `doc` could also be `null` according to that error. Did you verify that the xpath is the problem?

Comment: Use the debugger to detect if videoToAdd or doc is null.

Answer (score 6):

Your XML contains namespace specification, you need to modify your source to take that into consideration.
Example:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("doc.xml");
XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "UploadXSD");

videoToAdd.Title = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/ns:video/ns:title", xmlnsManager).InnerXml;
```

Comment: Correct answer but with a mistake, it should be `SelectSingleNode(@"/ns:video/ns:title", xmlnsManager)` as the title element also has the same namespace, and as you need to pass the manager to the SelectSingleNode for it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

`/video/title` would return a `title` element with no namespace, from within a `video` element with no namespace.

You need to either remove `xmlns="UploadXSD"` from your xml, or set an appropriate selection namespace in your C#

Answer (score 1):

It's the `xmlns="UploadXSD"` attribute causing you grief here.  I think you'll need to use a `XmlNamespaceManager` to help the parser resolve the names, or remove the `xmlns` attribute if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the `doc` variable points to the `<video>` element? In that case you would need to write either

```
videoToAdd.Title = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"./title").InnerXml;
```

or

```
videoToAdd.Title = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//video/title").InnerXml;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
videoToAdd.Title = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//xmlns:video/xmlns:title").InnerXml;
```

Your XML document has an XML namespace and to find the elements you must prefix them with `xmlns:`.

Comment: No, that would find an element with the namespace prefix (according to the context - of which there is none) xmlns, which isn't an allowed prefix. The above will return null from the SelectSingleNode, and then a NullReferenceException when you try to get InnerXML