# How do I set the namespace URI in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xsd, xml-namespaces

Im using a namespace in my xml (I need to use this for xsd validation purposes). Because of this my xpath is no longer working.

I have the code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(newXmlFilePath);
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<video xmlns="UploadXSD">
  <title>
    A vid with Pete
  </title>
  <description>
  Petes vid
  </description>
  <contributor>
    Pete
  </contributor>
  <subject>
    Cat 2
  </subject>
</video>
```

But my xpath doesnt select the node. I tried to set the namespace using:

```
doc.NamespaceUR = "x";
```

However its a get only accessor. Any ideas?

Comment: Already answered in your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312103/why-doesnt-this-xpath-c-work

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("vid", "UploadXSD");
```

Note that you need to use this with your query. For example:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("/vid:video/vid:subject", nsMgr);
```

As otherwise the `SelectSingleNode` won't know to operate in the context of that manager.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Microsoft How To: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318545

Answer (score 0):

Based on your other recent questions, I think you're trying to deal with a mixture of documents where some are in a particular namespace and some are not - so you're looking to be namespace-agnostic, right?

There are a couple of things you could do. You could use a [hack to strip out the namespace](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/keith/archive/2005/10/19/15714.aspx) - but that has always struck me as a bit fragile. There are other ways to express what is semantically the same document - e.g. the whole thing could use a namespace prefix on every single element - and that trick won't work.

Or you could write namespace-agnostic XPath queries. E.g. `"/*[local-name()='video']/*[local-name()='subject']"`